# replace in NSURL

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

How can I do a string replace in `NSURL`?
I tried `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` but it works with `NSString`.

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:dataList[indexPath.item][@"image"]];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

I want to replace image url

```
http://example.com/image1.jpg
```

to

```
http://example.com/img1.jpg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSURL` has an `absoluteString` method that you could use like so

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:dataList[indexPath.item][@"image"]];

NSString *urlString = [imageURL.absoluteString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"image" withString:@"img"];

imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

You could also directly operate on the NSString from the dataList as well:

```
NSString *urlString = [dataList[indexPath.item][@"image"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"image" withString:@"img"];

imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Comment: you're welcome. kindly accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:dataList[indexPath.item][@"image"]]; 
NSString *urlString = [imageURL.absoluteString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"image" withString:@"img"];
NSString *webStringURL = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];
```

Hope This will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to replace the last path component of the URL so use the dedicated API of `NSURL`:

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:dataList[indexPath.item][@"image"]];
NSURL *newURL = [[imageURL URLByDeletingLastPathComponent] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"img.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: newURL];
```

`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` could cause unexpected behavior.